# Scale Multiple Verts At Once To Line Them Up (like Maya)

Tags: modeling

Coming from Maya, if I have some verts that are supposed to be lined up on an axis but become unaligned slightly, I can just select them all, then scale them all at once and they all line up. This does not work in Blender. I searched for answers on this, but they seemed really convoluted (like 5-10 steps). Is there really not a simple equivalent in Blender to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: you mean align them to certain axis? scale to zero in that axis....

Comment: Scaling to zero in that axis puts them on a plane. If you want them for example to align to axis X, you need to scale them in Y an Z simultaneously. In Blender you do that with S then Shift+X then 0.

Comment: Thank you both. I was used to drag scaling -- in Blender, I had to select the axis and then scale. Worked fine.